# According to documentation photutils.aperture.CircularAperture does not accept a list of floats for 'r', what is the recommended method for this?

Tags: python, data-science, astropy, astronomy, photutils

It would be useful to combine `photutils.detection.IRAFStarFinder`'s ability to provide the fwhm of stars to the radius parameter of `photutils.aperture.CircularAperture` to construct a set of apertures, which can then be processed by `photutils.aperture.aperture_photometry` to yield the `aperture_sum`.

Unfortunately the CircularAperture only accepts singular floats. Is there a better aperture suited for this task?

- https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/photutils.detection.DAOStarFinder.html#photutils.detection.DAOStarFinder
- https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/photutils.detection.IRAFStarFinder.html
- https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/photutils/aperture/circle.html#CircularAperture
- https://photutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/photutils.aperture.aperture_photometry.html